# How to properly replace a symlink with the file in subversion?

Tags: svn

I have a symlink in our website called `index.php` which points to a script `controller.php`.

I'm want to remove the symlink then rename the `controller.php` to `index.php`. I'm doing this on 100's of files so I want to ensure I won't run into problems commiting and hopefully keep the history.

What I think is the correct thing to do is to remove the link using svn:

```
svn remove index.php
```

Followed by a svn rename

```
svn rename controller.php index.php
```

When I run svn status I get

```
D       htdocs/listener/v2/bbin/controller.php
R  +    htdocs/listener/v2/bbin/index.php
```

**Will this guarantee me that I won't have conflicts and will keep the history of the `controller.php` file?**

Comment: @vcsjones Thanks for confirming!

Comment: Everything you have stated seems correct, what is the question for us to answer? Have you tried the solution you explained?

Comment: @JesseWebb Thanks - I guess not having a question in a question is pretty bad form!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that status is correct; The `D` means that the file `htdocs/listener/v2/bbin/controller.php` will be deleted, and the `R` means that the file `htdocs/listener/v2/bbin/index.php` will be replaced. The `+` means that there is additional metadata being added with the commit, in this case, that the file is being replaced with `controller.php`.

Answer (score 1):

I would make a commit after the remove and before the rename. We run into tree conflicts over and over again if we tried to make both refactorings in one attempt.